# Does a subpoena's powers extend beyond the entity it is served to

Tags: united-states, subpoena

If a company is served with a subpoena, and it in turn emails all of its employees asking for any related documents, does the email carry the same powers as the original subpoena?  Jurisdiction: US federal law

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The e-mail has none of the powers of the subpoena. You may elect to ignore an e-mail from your boss (and get fired) but you may not elect to ignore a subpoena.

We don't have a lot of background here, but the more important question, probably, is the extent to which the employees are obligated to comply with the subpoena itself, and what penalties may apply to employees who refuse.

If a company is served with a subpoena under Rule 45(e), contempt of court is the only sanction, and Rule 45(e) only allows a finding of contempt against "a person who, *having been served*, fails without adequate excuse to obey the subpoena."

That service of the subpoena is a critical due process prerequisite, so it is not likely to be maneuvered around. So if an employee hasn't been served, my conclusion -- having never seen a case like this -- would be that the employee is not legally bound to comply.

Answer (score 0):

> does the email carry the same powers as the original subpoena?

Yes insofar as a non-compliant employee could be sanctioned for obstruction of justice. Employees are not allowed to disregard or to try to evade/overcome the company's email under pretext that they are not individually named in the subpoena.

Comment: Could you share some authority for this? I've never seen an obstruction conviction for failing to comply with an employer's e-mail purporting to comply with a subpoena.

Comment: @bdb484 See 18 USC §1512(b) and (c), which sanction whoever corruptly withholds or conceals (or attempts to, or persuades another to conceal) a record with the intent to impair its availability for use in an official proceeding. Whether or not the statute has been enforced in criminal court is a different issue, but the law is there. Also, under agency law "*nothing prevents [the employer] from pursuing legal remedies against those of his employees [at fault]*", [*Dark v. U.S.*, 641 F.2d 805, 807-8, n.4 (1981)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19811446641f2d80511316).

Comment: Not sure I agree. The ordinary sanction for failure to comply with a subpoena is contempt of court in the same case, and not a criminal charge, so obstruction of justice wouldn't be the same in any case. Usually, a subpoena is served upon a particular individual in a company, such as a records custodian or officer of the company, rather than the company itself, precisely to make it more readily enforceable by contempt. Contempt of court can be enforced against certain people with knowledge of the order rather than merely the subject of an order, but a non-compliant employee is a close case.

Comment: Agree with ohwilleke. And simply failing to comply with your employer's e-mail isn't the same thing as "corruptly" withholding or concealing a record "with the intent to impair its availability."

Comment: @ohwilleke Being a federal statute, 18 USC §1512 constitutes an *authority* which addresses obstruction of justice (via concealment of records) and sanctioning it with imprisonment. That being said, I agree that contempt of court is a softer and more frequent sanction than conviction in criminal court for withholding records.

Comment: It also appears that 18 USC § 1512 only applies to federal official proceedings, even though the intent need not be specific to a federal proceeding, so it has no application to a state court or state agency subpoena. https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1512

Comment: @bdb484 *Intent* is relevant for both obstruction of justice and a finding of contempt, since a court wouldn't find someone in contempt if the person's non-compliance was inadvertent. If necessary, the circumstances and terms of the email would help identifying whether the non-compliant employee entertained a corrupt intent. For instance, non-compliance would tend to weigh against the employee if the email was sent by the employer's attorney or director.

Comment: @ohwilleke "*It also appears that 18 USC § 1512 only applies to federal official proceedings*". That's fine because OP's inquiry ends with "Jurisdiction: Federal law".

Comment: @IñakiViggers Fair. Also worth noting that direct enforcement of a subpoena issued in a civil case is allowed under Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 45 only upon a person who has been personally served with the subpoena. https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_45 Criminal actions requires the consent of a federal prosecutor to move forward.

Comment: Most of what you're saying does not make great sense, but I guess my original question stands. Has there ever been a successful obstruction prosecution based on failure to comply with an employer's email?

Comment: @bdb484 You initially asked for "*some authority for this*" and I provided one: A federal statute which has not been repealed. In the very next sentence (same comment) I also signaled that I don't know whether it has ever been enforced in criminal court. You're evidently smart, so it's odd that *most* of this "*does not make great sense*" to you. An employee's culpable state of mind in failing to comply with employer's *request for records* might be determined or discarded through further discovery and circumstantial evidence, and this could very well be within the purview of 18 USC § 1512.

Comment: The obstruction statute is a good authority for the existence of the obstruction offense; it's not really great authority for its applicability to these facts.

Comment: @bdb484 One modality of obstruction as listed in the statute is the concealment or withholding of records. [18 USC § 1512](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1512) is not even premised on the issuance of a subpoena, whence sanctions may arise if the proof of intent, materiality of the omission, and (as ohwilleke points out) prosecutor's discretion outweigh the circumstantial fact that the employer's request for records was made through email. I've never said that a non-compliant employee will inevitably be sanctioned, but sanctions are not precluded either.

Comment: Yes, and if the facts reveal that the employee owed allegiance to the United States, and failed to comply with the e-mail in order to give aid and comfort to its enemies, then sanctions may arise for treason. But I don't see the point of inventing new facts to shoehorn the original question into the first criminal statute I think of.

Comment: @bdb484 I didn't invent any new facts. The law is hardly ever a static/simple yes-no question. It is often necessary to *qualify* an answer because other intrinsic details/factors may come into play. Here, the sole and bare pretext that the request for records was in the form of email (rather than a subpoena with the employee's name on it) will not automatically exempt that employee from the possibility of sanctions.

Comment: After reading the referenced law, I feel that an obstruction charge might be successfully prosecuted but my question was about a subpoena's powers specifically. Thanks for the additional info though.